# Can't read what the socket is receiving from server Android

Tags: android, sockets, client

I've been trying to connect a socket to a server to send some data provided by the user in order to register to a tracking service, the server is receiving the data and I can read it, my problem is that the server is supposed to answer me something and I'm not sure if the Socket is getting it.

I'm using a Toast to show what the variable is holding after the server answers but it doesn't show anything, that's why I think I'm doing something wrong with my socket implementation.

```
public void btnRegistrar(View view) {

        name = nombre.getText().toString();
        last = apellido.getText().toString();
        mail = correo.getText().toString();
        num = numero.getText().toString();
        ID = collar.getText().toString();

        if(name.matches("") || last.matches("") || mail.matches("") || num.matches("") || ID.matches("")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Favor de llenar todos los campos para poder continuar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(num.length()<10){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Favor de ingresar su número a 10 dígitos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            registro = name + "," + last + "," + mail + "," + num + "," + ID + "," + "0";
            Registro(registro);
            saveProperties();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewMapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } // btnRegistrar

    public void Registro (String str){
        final String Registro = str;

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Socket client = new Socket(ip2, port);
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeObject(Registro);
                    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                    AppID = (String) in.readObject();
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    client.close();
                }catch (UnknownHostException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), AppID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } // Registro`
```

Comment: Socket connection code is written in a different thread and the code to display the toast is written outside new thread code.? Is this done deliberately? Move it inside the thread and check.

Comment: I already did that but then the Toast doesn't show up, that's why I put it out the Thread, the String variable is global, so I thought that it would get the value from the server and I could use it outside the thread.

Comment: May be try to add logs i side thread and see that you really receiving any data

Comment: Your Toast is on the wrong place as it will be executeted before the run(). Place a start value in AppId and you will see that start value. You should place that Toast in a call to runOnUiThread() which you place as last statement in run().